# Is there a way to get a scatter plot chart for an Azure DevOps query?

Tags: charts, azure-devops

I want to be able to create scatter plot charts in order to easily graph the impact, value, and effort of a project. is there a plug-in or some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this time, however, creating scatter plot chart with custom data is not supported.

Also, I have looked through the extension market but found no extension can meet your requirement.

[Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=chart&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&visibilityQuery=all&sortBy=Relevance) is the search results for charts in the market.